# How do I clear a suggestion from history-beginning-search-backward or history-beginning-search-forward?

Tags: bash, zsh, command-history, readline

How do I clear a suggestion when `history-beginning-search-backward` is invoked?

For example:

```
sudo vim
#history-beginning-search-backward gets executed by a keybinding
sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

Once in that state, how can I go back to `sudo vim`?

It would be useful to know for both Bash and ZSH.

Comment: I updated your title as the initial one repeated itself. Please re-correct it if I misinterpreted your intention.